# Errors during deployment to AWS using Terraform (cdktf)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, cdktf

I am trying to create or update Lambdas on AWS using the Terraform CDKTF. During deployment, I am getting the error of

```
"An event source mapping with SQS arn (\" arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:*******:*****-*****-******** \") and function (\" ******-******-****** \") already exists. Please update or delete the existing mapping with UUID *******-****-****-****-***********"
```

**** are sensitive info I have swapped out.

Some of our Lambdas are called via SQS, which is what this mapping is referring to. I assumed the first fix would be to remove the mappings that might already exist (on a previous deployment that might have partly gone through), but I am unsure where to find them, nor if they are even available to delete. I originally assumed by calling `cdktf deploy` it would update these mappings and not throw the err at all.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: If you have the UUID of this event source map, you can delete it using `aws lambda delete-event-source-mapping --uuid <value>`. Just be careful because there is no way to revert it.

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis seems right, there might be some stray resources left behind due to an aborted / unfinished Terraform run. You should be able to clean up after these runs by running `terraform destroy` in the stack directory `./cdktf.out/stacks/..../`. That should delete all previously existing resources created through this Terraform stack.